# How to align three items in single row in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I'm having problem with items alignment in `universal theme 42`.

Please look into the picture below,

[image]

All of the shown `page-items` are having `label column span` = 1.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid is based on 12 columns. You have to use the grid as Bootstrap principle.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

It means that you can't overcome 12 columns for each row. 
In the image that you uploaded in this post I would use 4 columns each item or less depends of the size.

Let me know if you have more questions.